# Overflow visible not visible on the right

Tags: css, overflow

I'm working on a pricing table and have an issue with one of the divs. The middle container should overflow the other containers but it only does it at the left side. The container at the right is overlapping the middle one which it shouldn't. How can I fix this?

I've made a JSfiddle, the problem is with the biggest container (Flex I) in the middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gBCCP/

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.pricingtable {z-index: 1;}
.pricingtable.featuredbig {position: relative;}
```

Seems to solve the problem.

Comment: It does indeed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fyp9y/

Use

```
position:relative;
```

On the containers

And [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to specify the order of overlaying. I've used inline styles for a quick demonstration but you can tidy this up. By the way I like your design!

Comment: Thanks, all the credits for the design goes to Designshack; http://designshack.net/articles/css/csspricingtables/ I'm just editing the code for my own needs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do to using  position:relative and z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/gBCCP/2/